# How can I use querySelectorAll with htmx

Tags: javascript, html, htmx

I am working with htmx which is a fantastic library, I have a little problem that's not very clear on how to solve. htmx uses queryselector to locate elements to swap/update example with `hx-swap="..."`, `hx-target="..."` how do I do a querySelectorAll. example I have a class bookmark, when a user bookmarks a post, I want to update all the classes with `.bookmark`

Comment: If you have to use `querySelectorAll` on a HTMX attribute, you are doing something wrong. When an user bookmarks a post, you want to save it into the database, so you make a request via HTMX. The backend saves the bookmark and returns an updated HTML content. This is where and when you should add the `.bookmark` class. After that HTMX swaps the old content with the new one and the user sees the updated content with the `.bookmark` class added.

Answer (score 1):

You'd use the [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```js
const hxSwap = document.querySelectorAll('[hx-swap]');
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you can do also like this :

```
let swapOrTarget = document.querySelectorAll("[hx-swap]") || document.querySelectorAll("[hx-target]");
```